# If I use sound wave in Michelson Morley experimental set up will this wave interfare?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, relativity

We know that light waves do not interfere in the Michelson Morley experiment, and this is where the concept of relativity came. But I can not admit it. We made this experiment on earth. For some brief interval we can consider it to be an inertial frame.

We also know that Newtonian mechanics hold for inertial frame. When I encounter it I can not find the problem!

If earth is considered to be a inertial frame then where is the violation?? We made the experiment on earth so it should not have any path difference naturally. And my assumption is that the sound wave would also not interfere in that set up which has very low speed compare to light.

Now being inefficient I don't know if it is true. But if I go wrong then please make me understand it so that my doubts gets completely away from me. Thank you.

Comment: sound is variations in pressure in a medium.  The michelson morley experiment wanted to prove the medium of the aether,, and found that there is no medium. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment

Comment: But how did the theory of relativity came in. It's from Michelson Morley experiment?? But how plz explain.

Comment: the theory of relativity is the Lorenz transformations that are inherent within Maxwells equations in vacuum. the mm experiment showed that there is aether, so the vacuum is empty .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#History

Comment: the mm experiment is consistent with the theory of relativity, but the theory of relativity came about by Einstein postulating that not only maxwell's equations are consistent with Lorentz transformations with massless photons , but also massive particles obeyed  Lorenz transformations  A hypothesis that has been confirmed with nuclear and particle physics experiments. see https://www.energy.gov/sites/prod/files/The%20History%20of%20Nuclear%20Energy_0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> And my assumption is that the sound wave will also not interfare in that set up which has very low speed compare to light.

In principle, if you made a Michelson interferometer with sound waves then it would produce interference in the wind and you could use the interference to measure the speed of the wind through the device.

> If earth is considered to be a inertial frame then where is the violation??

“Violation” is a little strong. The point is that there was no equivalent of the wind for light. They tested at different times of day and throughout the year. If the earth were moving through a rigid aether then there should have been some “aether wind” at some point. There was not. So the experiment ruled out the popular rigid aether concept of contemporary scientists.